# How to create a WindowsIdentity using a username string such as "JohnDoe" in C#

Tags: c#, windows-identity

I have the `isAdministrator(String a)` as follows:

```
public static bool IsAdministrator(String aString)
{
    WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(a);
    WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
    return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
}
```

Where `aString` is a username. When I ran this I realized I need a UPN. Is there anyway around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need this for unit testing or are you trying to impersonate a known Windows account?

Comment: I am trying to impersonate a known Windows account